# Ethereum with Nvidia Jetson TX1 - test graphics chip's mining capabilities

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, compilation

I want to just test if my Nvidia Jetson TX1 board can do ETH mining. I do not intent to use it for ETH mining, but still want to explore if it's possible or not.

Here are Nvidia Jetson TX1 hardware specs details:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-tx1-module.html

I was trying to setup development environment to compile `geth` and when I tried running ARM version of `go` library it was giving me error of `no such executable binary found` etc.

https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.6.2.linux-armv6l.tar.gz

I just want to test if this boards's Graphics chip can do mining of any Crypto coin. So, I just picked ETH to give it a try with.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an interesting project. On a quick trip through google I could not find any go binaries for `ARM 64` devices. The binary you linked is for ARMv6 architctures, but the Jetson TX1 is ARM64.

But good news for you, you don't have to build geth from source, Peter offers cross builds for almost any platform, including ARM64 [on bintray](https://bintray.com/karalabe/ethereum/geth/view):

Direct link: [`geth-1.4.7-stable-667a386-linux-arm64.tar.bz2`](https://bintray.com/karalabe/ethereum/download_file?file_path=geth-1.4.7-stable-667a386-linux-arm64.tar.bz2)

Happy testing.

Comment: Thanks mate! That's Amazing! I'll give that binary a try on my Jetson TX1 :)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. the pre-compiled binary doesn't have support for OpenCL.  `./geth gpuinfo`
`OpenCL disabled. Set GO_OPENCL and re-build to enable.`

Comment: More detail is here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6771/geth-opencl-disabled-set-go-opencl-and-re-build-to-enable